# Keycloak reset user password

Tags: java, authentication, keycloak, bcrypt

I have a user in keycloak and I want to reset his password.

The password already exists in DB and is created via Spring's `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.

This is my new password: `$2a$10$.Y5G9KV1JCToOifuzvbZf.guYplSLnpqmNkPdD2k2IZc3wNAMpyjC`

And this is how i try to reset existing one:

```
CredentialRepresentation newCreds = new CredentialRepresentation();
newCreds.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
newCreds.setHashedSaltedValue(newPassword);
newCreds.setAlgorithm("bcrypt");
newCreds.setTemporary(false);

getKeycloakClient().realm("master").users().get(userId).resetPassword(newCreds);
```

It doesn't work. I get error: `javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request`

But when I change it to:

```
CredentialRepresentation newCreds = new CredentialRepresentation();
newCreds.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
newCreds.setValue("testPassword");
newCreds.setTemporary(false);

getKeycloakClient().realm("master").users().get(userId).resetPassword(newCreds);
```

It works fine.

How can I reset password in keycloak by using already existed password encrypted with BCrypt?

**EDIT:**

Now I know I have to send also salt for my password by setting `newCreds.setSalt(salt)` but there still is one problem. Keycloak accepts Base64 for this and Spring's BCryptPasswordEncoder generates values with `.` character which is not accepted in BAse64

Comment: I think your error is related to the algorithm name
it is better to encrypt the password via  java library and send it as text to keycloak without using setAlgorithm

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Keycloak Admin API:

1. [Rest API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/index.html)
2. [Java Client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-admin-client/18.0.2):
3. [Nodejs Client](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-admin-client)

There is a nice [tutorial](https://dev.to/carnewal/import-existing-users-with-bcrypt-hashed-passwords-in-keycloak-17oo) written by Brecht Carnewal

First you have to install keycloak-bcrypt and the jbcrypt library on your keycloak instance

```
KEYCLOAK_HOME=~/keycloak

curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mindrot/jbcrypt/0.4/jbcrypt-0.4.jar > jbcrypt-0.4.jar
$KEYCLOAK_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --command="module add --name=org.mindrot.jbcrypt --resources=jbcrypt-0.4.jar"

curl -L https://github.com/leroyguillaume/keycloak-bcrypt/releases/download/1.2.0/keycloak-bcrypt-1.2.0.jar > $KEYCLOAK_HOME/standalone/deployments/keycloak-bcrypt-1.2.0.jar
```

Restart Keycloak and then setup bcrypt hashing algorithm from the admin panel under Authentication -> Password Policy.

Write and run your script

```
import KeycloakAdminClient from 'keycloak-admin';
const {
  AUTH_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
  AUTH_REALM_NAME = 'myRealmName',
  AUTH_ADMIN_USERNAME = 'admin',
  AUTH_ADMIN_PASSWORD = 'admin',
  AUTH_ADMIN_CLIENT = 'admin-cli',
  AUTH_ADMIN_SECRET = 'jriozejrioezjriorez',
  // ^ needed if your admin-cli client is set to confidential
} = process.env;

const authClient = new KeycloakAdminClient({
  baseUrl: AUTH_URL, // http://localhost:8080/auth
  realmName: AUTH_REALM_NAME,
});

const startMigration = async ({ database }) => {
  await authClient.auth({
    username: AUTH_ADMIN_USERNAME,
    password: AUTH_ADMIN_PASSWORD,
    clientId: AUTH_ADMIN_CLIENT, // probably admin-cli
    // only needed if your admin client is set to confidential
    clientSecret: AUTH_ADMIN_SECRET,
    grantType: 'password',
  });

  const existingUsers = await database.users.find();

  for (let existingUser of existingUsers) {
    const user = {
      realm: AUTH_REALM_NAME,
      credentials: [
        {
          algorithm: 'bcrypt',
          hashedSaltedValue: existingUser.password, // the bcrypt-hashed password
          hashIterations: 10,
          type: 'password',
        },
      ],
      email: existingUser.email,
      username: existingUser.email,
      emailVerified: true,
      enabled: true,
    };
    await authClient.users.create(user);
  }
};
```